# Second DropdownList will not be Filled

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I've used two Cascade DDLs on my Page.
The method of work is that when the selected item DDL1 changes, the corresponding information should be filled in DDL2 .
I used jQuery to call the DDL2 filler function:
When I select DDL1 item, the `FillTypes` function is called and the corresponding records are passed to the jQuery ,But this items is not filled in DDL2 .
I do not know where is my problem?

i attached screenshot

[image: Code]

[image: DDl2 runtime, Which is not filled]

[image: Browser debug mode]

controler:

```html
 ' GET: MachinInfo/Create
        Function MachinInfoAdd() As ActionResult
            ViewBag.BrandID = New SelectList(db.Brand, "Id", "BrandName")
            ViewBag.MachineID = New SelectList(db.MachinKind, "Id", "MachinName")
            ViewBag.MachinStateID = New SelectList(db.MachinState, "Id", "Title")
            ViewBag.PelakStateID = New SelectList(db.PelakState, "Id", "Title")
            ViewBag.GeartypeID = New SelectList(db.GearType, "Id", "Title")

            Return View()


        End Function

        ' POST: MachinInfo/Create
        'To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        'more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        <HttpPost()>
        <ValidateAntiForgeryToken()>
        Function MachinInfoAdd(<Bind(Include:="Id,PelakStateID,MachinStateID,OrgCode,MachineID,BrandID,MachintypeID,NPlate,NPlateL,NPlateM,NPlateR,CardSerial,VIN,Chasis,Motor,Myear,Color,GearTypeID,MCost,Mcamp,Description")> ByVal machinInfo As MachinInfo) As ActionResult
            If ModelState.IsValid Then
                ' If machinInfo.NPlate Is Nothing = False Then machinInfo.NPlate = machinInfo.NPlate.Replace("ایران", "").Replace(" ", "").Replace("-", "")
                db.MachinInfo.Add(machinInfo)
                db.SaveChanges()
                Return RedirectToAction("Index")
            End If

            ViewBag.BrandID = New SelectList(db.Brand, "Id", "BrandName", "SelectedBrandID")
            ViewBag.MachineID = New SelectList(db.MachinKind, "Id", "MachinName")
            ViewBag.MachinStateID = New SelectList(db.MachinState, "Id", "Title")
            ViewBag.PelakStateID = New SelectList(db.PelakState, "Id", "Title")
            ViewBag.GeartypeID = New SelectList(db.GearType, "Id", "Title")
            Return View(machinInfo)
        End Function
        
        
          Public Function FillTypes(ByVal MachinKindId As Integer) As JsonResult

            Dim MachinTypes = db.MachinType.Where(Function(c) c.MachinKindId = MachinKindId).ToArray
            Return Json(MachinTypes, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)

        End Function
```

model:

```html
Partial Public Class MachinType
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property MachinTypeName As String
    Public Property BrandId As Integer
    Public Property MachinKindId As Integer

    Public Overridable Property MachinInfo As ICollection(Of MachinInfo) = New HashSet(Of MachinInfo)
    Public Overridable Property Brand As Brand
    Public Overridable Property MachinKind As MachinKind

End Class
```

view:

```html
@ModelType Machinary.MachinInfo
@Code
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.vbhtml"
End Code

@Using (Html.BeginForm("MachinInfoAdd", "MachinInfo", FormMethod.Post))

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    @<div class="panel">
      

        <div Class="form-horizontal panel-body">

            @Html.ValidationSummary(True, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
            

            <div class="row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.MachintypeID, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <select id="MachintypeID" name="MachintypeID" class="form-control"></select>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                    
                     @Html.LabelFor(Function(model) model.MachineID, htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "control-label col-md-2"})
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.DropDownList("MachineID", Nothing, "انتخاب کنید", htmlAttributes:=New With {.class = "form-control"})
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(model) model.MachineID, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="ُSave" class="btn btn-success" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <br />
              </div>
              End Using




@section MyScripts

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#MachineID').change(function () {
                var machineid = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url: "FillTypes",
                    data: "{MachinKindId:'" + machineid + "'}",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $('#MachintypeID').empty();
                        $('#MachintypeID').append('<option selected="selected" value="">Select Machintype</option>')
                        $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                            $('#MachintypeID').append('<option value=' + d.Id + '>' + d.MachinTypeName + '</option>');
                        });

                    },
                    failure: function (data) {
                        alert('error occured');
                    }

                });
            });
        });
    </script>
End Section
```

Comment: Try remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` and replace `data` with `data: { MachinKindId: machineid }` since you're not passing JSON string with `JSON.stringify()`, but passing a value directly.

Answer (score 1):

With the tests I did, I realized that the problem in the code loop section is high. Because the loop part never runs. `alert('a')` always runs but `alert('b')` is never seen. And remember that `FillTypes` function will return the records

```
success: function (data) {
                    $('#MachintypeID').empty();
                    $('#MachintypeID').append('<option selected="selected" value="">Select Machintype</option>')
                    alert('a');
                    $.each(data, function (i, d) {
                        //$('#MachintypeID').append('<option>' + d.MachinTypeName + '</option>');
                        alert('b' );
                    });

                },`
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to pass `MachinKindId` value as single parameter, it's unnecessary to use `contentType` setting, just pass it directly instead with GET method:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET", // use GET method
    dataType: "json",
    url: '@Url.Action("FillTypes", "ControllerName")',
    data: { MachinKindId: machineid },
    success: function (data) {
        $('#MachintypeID').empty();
        $('#MachintypeID').append('<option selected="selected" value="">Select Machintype</option>')
        $.each(data, function (i, d) {
            $('#MachintypeID').append('<option value=' + d.Id + '>' + d.MachinTypeName + '</option>');
        });
    },
    failure: function (data) {
        alert('error occured');
    }
});
```

**Note:**

I noticed you're not using `<HttpPost()>` attribute on top of `FillTypes` action and `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` is used, therefore the `type` option must be set as `GET` because by default action methods have implicit `<HttpGet()>` attribute unless `<HttpPost()>` attribute is specified.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Changes have been made but the problem has not been resolved. Please see the attached images.

Comment: Currently I don't see where you put `MachineID` select element, hence you should check for browser console errors. Refer to [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/JS6Klk) for working example based on the answer's code.

Comment: With the tests I did, I realized that the problem in the code loop section is high. Because the loop part never runs. `alert('a')` always runs but `alert('b')` is never seen. And remember that `FillTypes` function will return the records. Please see my new post

Comment: Check the `data` content using `console.log(data)` before `$.each()`. If it returns an array, then your AJAX should be fine; but if nothing was returned, then you need to fix the data array.